# Rails server exiting after startup after running rake db:migrate in previous session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am having issues starting a rails server after having run rake db:migrate in a previous session. I had installed devise and was setting up a new database in my app, which seems to have worked fine, but I have not been able to start a new server after restarting my app. Any thoughts?

```
Taylors-MacBook-Pro:pinteresting taylorburton$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.0 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:457:in `ensure in with_devise_exclusive_scope': undefined method `merge!' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Scope:0x007f7fdbea1f70> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:457:in `with_devise_exclusive_scope'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:248:in `block (2 levels) in devise_for'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:351:in `block in devise_scope'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:940:in `block in constraints'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:816:in `scope'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:940:in `constraints'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:350:in `devise_scope'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:247:in `block in devise_for'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `each'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `devise_for'
    from /Users/taylorburton/Desktop/pinteresting/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:423:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:423:in `eval_block'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:401:in `draw'
    from /Users/taylorburton/Desktop/pinteresting/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/taylorburton/Desktop/pinteresting/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
    from /Users/taylorburton/Desktop/pinteresting/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Users/taylorburton/Desktop/pinteresting/config.ru:in `new'
    from /Users/taylorburton/Desktop/pinteresting/config.ru:in `<main>'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598@global/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in `start'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/taylorburton/Desktop/pinteresting/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /Users/taylorburton/Desktop/pinteresting/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/spring-1.3.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/taylorburton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/spring-1.3.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/taylorburton/Desktop/pinteresting/bin/spring:13:in `require'
    from /Users/taylorburton/Desktop/pinteresting/bin/spring:13:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Could you include the first few lines of `config/routes.rb` file? The error message is pointing to line # 2 of this file.

Comment: @Taylor : you are on rails 4.2 beta version an this a bug in devise 

check : https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3206

Comment: Sure thing Prakash: Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
root "pages#home"
get "about" => "pages#about" #creates about_path

Comment: @PrakashMurthy, problem solved! Answer below. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

in your Gemfile, change the version as so:

```
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.0'
```

than run in your terminal:

```
bundle update devise
```

Comment: @Taylor Burton No prob! Glad it worked! Perhaps consider accepting it as correct answer, if ya don't mind :)

Comment: Oh sorry about that! Brand spankin' new to this forum. Thanks again!