# Trouble installing Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am using rails for a quick project. I try to run rake:db migrate after *rails g devise User* on the command line and I get this error log:

```
Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:457:in `ensure in with_devise_exclusive_scope': undefined method `merge!' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Scope:0x007fcbe5e766f8> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:457:in `with_devise_exclusive_scope'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:248:in `block (2 levels) in devise_for'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:351:in `block in devise_scope'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:940:in `block in constraints'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:816:in `scope'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:940:in `constraints'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:350:in `devise_scope'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:247:in `block in devise_for'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `each'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.3.0/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:223:in `devise_for'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/Rails-Blog/config/routes.rb:3:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:432:in `eval_block'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:410:in `draw'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/Rails-Blog/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:446:in `block in make_lambda'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:192:in `call'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:192:in `block in simple'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:83:in `prepare!'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:55:in `prepare!'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/ashleighalmeida/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I configured it in enviornment.rb, added my alerts, what could be the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails server exiting after startup after running rake db:migrate in previous session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265651/rails-server-exiting-after-startup-after-running-rake-dbmigrate-in-previous-ses)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you hadn't properly installed Devise when you generated the User model.

To resolve this problem, run this command

```
rails g devise:install
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in this version of Devise with Rails. You can update to a newer version.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29265651/rails-server-exiting-after-startup-after-running-rake-dbmigrate-in-previous-ses) should help you to solve the problem.